# Android emulator freezes at startup on windows 7 32 bit

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

My system configuration is following
**Processor : Intel Pentium dual core T2370 with 1.73 GHz
RAM : 2 GB
OS : windows-7 32 bit**

I've installed Android ADT bundle (Eclipse JUNO,ADT plugin) after that I have successfully install Android SDK build-in tool and Android 4.4W (API20) with other stuff. Then I've  created AVD with Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System image, but when I try to start the emulator, it freezes and the screen remains black (I tried to wait for over 15 minutes).

I have tried many AVD with different configuration of RAM, internal storage but nothing is going to work for me.

Please help me. I have waste many hours on searching Google and all that.

**My AVD configuration is :**
**AVD NAME**: Android_20
**DeVICE**: 4" WVGA (Nexus S)480*800 hdpi
**CPU**: Android Wear ARM(armeabi v7a)
**Skin**: WVGA800
**Camera front and rear** : none
**RAM** : 512 
**Heap** : 32 
**Internal storage** : 1000 MB 
**Sd card**:None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get [genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) my friends it will helps you a lot in many things.

and for this default emulator , check what you set in CPU/ABI , set it as ARM

Comment: thanks for your answer, but when I go through genymotion website it show that the free version support only limited feature. Is it cause any problem later

Comment: if you feel right or comfort ans for you than please tick to true.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the Host GPU option and try again. I would also recommend installing the Hardware Accelerated Execution Manger and turning ON Virtualization technology in your BIOS to get the emulator running faster. Also post your AVD config .

Comment: I am unable to install Hardware Accelerated Execution Manger because my system not support Virtualization technology, I have check it on Intel's website. I am also add AVD configuration in my question